# Upgrading to firebase-messaging 19.0.0 and up breaks kotlinx's synthetic

Tags: firebase, gradle, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, synthetic

When I upgrade to firebase-messaging 19.0.0 and up it seems to cause conflict with kotlinx synthetic. The existing imports for synthetics are unused when I try with version 19. I didn't migrate to androidx yet.

Anybody has seen this issue ?

Comment: Please file a bug report with Firebase support if you have a reproduction steps.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support